# plugin-under-test-metadata.properties not created by Gradle TestKit when running tests in IDEA

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle 3.3 and trying to test a custom plugin with JUnit and Gradle TestKit. In plugin's `build.gradle` I have

```groovy
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':codegen-core')
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The test is

```groovy
package com.huawei.odmf.codegen.gradle

import org.gradle.testkit.runner.BuildResult
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder

import static org.junit.Assert.*

class TestOdmfCodegenPlugin {

    @Rule 
    public final TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder()

    private File buildFile
    private File assetsDir

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile("build.gradle")
        assetsDir = testProjectDir.newFolder("src", "main", "assets")
    }

    @Test
    void testPlugin() {
        buildFile << """
          plugins {
          id 'com.huawei.odmf'
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        odmf {
            modelFile 'odmf.xml'
        }
        """

        BuildResult result = GradleRunner.create().
                withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root).
                withArguments(OdmfCodegenPlugin.taskName).
                withPluginClasspath().
                build()

        // assertions
    }
}
```

Under `src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.huawei.odmf.properties` I have

```
implementation-class=com.huawei.odmf.codegen.gradle.OdmfCodegenPlugin
```

This seems to be all that's required according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sub:test-kit-automatic-classpath-injection and the `automaticClasspathInjectionQuickstart` sample.

However, this test fails at `withPluginClasspath()` (EDIT: when run in IDEA; it works from command line) with the following stack trace (to my understanding, `plugin-under-test-metadata.properties` is supposed to be created by `java-gradle-plugin` automatically):

```
org.gradle.testkit.runner.InvalidPluginMetadataException: Test runtime classpath does not contain plugin metadata file 'plugin-under-test-metadata.properties'

  at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.readImplementationClasspath(PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.java:44)
  at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.readImplementationClasspath(PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.java:37)
  at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.DefaultGradleRunner.withPluginClasspath(DefaultGradleRunner.java:146)
  at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.DefaultGradleRunner$withPluginClasspath$0.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
  at com.huawei.odmf.codegen.gradle.TestOdmfCodegenPlugin.testPlugin(TestOdmfCodegenPlugin.groovy:40)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
  at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
  at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I remember you don't need to call `withPluginClasspath()` explicitly. Try without calling it explicitly. If it works, tell me, then I make this an answer.

Comment: @Vampire Unfortunately, it doesn't: "Plugin [id: 'com.huawei.odmf'] was not found in any of the following sources"

Comment: @Vampire It doesn't work from command line either, but it turns out that the version which does call `withPluginClasspath()` does.

Comment: Ah, ok, interesting. Unfortunately the repo of that plugin is deleted or private.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate. I also can't switch to 4.0 and check if the problem is still there, so I don't know if I should report the bug to Gradle.

Comment: @Vampire Even weirder, the plugin is actually intended to fix a different bug which was fixed in 2.14: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/nosuchmethoderror-in-testkit-after-2-9-2-10-transition/13505/12

Comment: Same problem in 5.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```groovy
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext" version "0.4.2"
}

task fixIdeaPluginClasspath {
    doFirst {
        configure(tasks.pluginUnderTestMetadata) {
            def ideaClassesPath = project.buildDir.toPath().resolveSibling("out").resolve("production")
            def newClasspath = pluginClasspath as List
            newClasspath.add(0, ideaClassesPath)
            pluginClasspath.setFrom(newClasspath)
        }
    }
}
pluginUnderTestMetadata.mustRunAfter(fixIdeaPluginClasspath)

idea.project.settings {
    taskTriggers {
        beforeBuild fixIdeaPluginClasspath, pluginUnderTestMetadata
    }
}
```

This works with IDEA 2019.1 (and may very well work with earlier versions as well).

This utilizes [JetBrains' own gradle plugin for configuring IDEA settings](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin) to execute both `pluginUnderTestMetadata` and the custom `fixIdeaPluginClasspath` before each build (the latter will only run from within the IDEA, not when running native gradle).

The first task -- `pluginUnderTestMetadata` -- makes sure to create the properties file, and is executed by native Gradle as well.

The second task -- `fixIdeaPluginClasspath` -- fixes another bug with how IDEA executes tests: The classpath generated by `pluginUnderTestMetadata` will only contain reference to the `"$projectDir/build"` directory, which is not where IDEA outputs its compiled classes; hence, you will not see changes you've made in the plugin code that were compiled by IDEA, but only those compiled by native gradle. What it does then is to prepend the IDEA classes directory to the classpath. At first I also tried removing the `"$projectDir/build"` reference(s), but gradle then didn't like it complaining about plugin namespace problems (too voodoo for me).

Thanks to [@krzychu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537441) for pointing out `pluginUnderTestMetadata` (on an earlier answer's comment).

Comment: I've also opened a bug for them: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206158

Answer (score 17):

After determining the problem was in IDEA only, I've found https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.palantir.idea-test-fix and added

```
plugins {
  id "com.palantir.idea-test-fix" version "0.1.0"
}
```

to the beginning of `build.gradle` for the plugin subproject. It fixes the problem.

In [this post (Russian)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282924/), I found another solution: in `Settings-> Build-> Build Tools->Gradle->Runner`, select `Gradle Test Runner` instead of `Platform Test Runner`, then delete the test's run/debug configuration before running it again.

Comment: I had the same problem with IntelliJ 2017.2.   I couldn't get the com.palantir.idea-test-fix to work, but the trick to change to the gradle test runner worked great!

Comment: BTW, this issue occurred for me while trying to use the vanilla gradle plugin example documented here:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sub:test-kit-automatic-classpath-injection

Comment: Problem still occurs with IDEA 2017.2.5 and Gradle 4.3. Changing the runner and deleting the run configurations fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Described solutions didn't solve the problem for me, but running `./gradlew pluginUnderTestMetadata` did.

Comment: In IDEA 2020.2 only way to fix it was to go in `Settings>Build>Gradle>YOUR_PROJECT>Run tests using` and select `Gradle (Default)`

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle 4, I was trying to use `gradleTestKit()` and got this error.

- adding the below plugin fixed it.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I got the same error when I used gradleTestKit _without_ the above line, when I searched google, I found your question. I know StackOverflow doesn't like irrelevant answers so we really can't answer side questions :(

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sub:test-kit-automatic-classpath-injection

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening due to `pluginUnderTestMetadata` not being executed before the tests. That's what generates the metadata, which your execution is complaining about.

A way to fix this is to add that task as a requirement for your tests:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    dependsOn("pluginUnderTestMetadata")
}
```

Some test executors might not catch this before executing tests. As a workaround you can depend on that when compiling your test classes:

```kotlin
tasks.named("testClasses") {
    dependsOn("pluginUnderTestMetadata")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `build.gradle.kts` (kotlin) you can use:

```kotlin
    val createClasspathManifest = tasks.create("createClasspathManifest") {
        val outputDir = file("$buildDir/$name")
    
        inputs.files(sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath)
        inputs.files(project(":core").sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath)
    
        outputs.dir(outputDir)
        doLast {
            outputDir.mkdirs()
    
            val joined = sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath.joinToString("\n") +
                    project(":core").sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath.joinToString("\n")
    
            file("$outputDir/plugin-classpath.txt").writeText(joined)
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        testApi(files(createClasspathManifest))
    }
```